# contact form in php isn't working

Tags: php

```
  if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))  {

  //Email information
  $admin_email = "neelaitken@hotmail.com";

  $name = $_REQUEST['name'];

  $email = $_REQUEST['email'];

  $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];

  $comment = $_REQUEST['comment'];




  //send email

  mail($admin_email, $name, "$subject", $comment, "From:" . $email);

  //Email response

  echo "Thank you for contacting us!";
  }

  //if "email" variable is not filled out, display the form

  else  {

          ?>

 <form method="post">

                                  <div>
                                <span><input name="name" type="text" class="textbox" value="Name:" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Name*';}"></span>
                            </div>

                            <div>
                                <span><input name="email"  type="text" class="textbox" value="Email:" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Email*';}"></span>
                            </div>




                            <div>
                                <span><input name="subject" type="text" class="textbox" value="mobile:" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'subject and phone*';}"></span>
                            </div>

                            <div>
                                <span><textarea name="comment" value="Message:" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Message*';}">Message</textarea></span>
                            </div>

                           <div>
                                <span><input type="submit" value="Submit"></span>
                          </div>  
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: What is the problem? `isn't working` is not telling us your problem

Comment: What happens when you run this code? An error? Nothing? The wrong person gets the email? No one does? The wrong text is sent?

Comment: not getting email which i specified  $admin_email = "neelaitken@hotmail.com";

Comment: @neelgurbani - OK. What is the return value from `mail()`? What is in your mail server logs? Are you sure there is a mail server running? Do different email addresses work?

Comment: #ryan_kempt mail() function is working properly on local host and order that i know is correct.
#andrewsi I've just written this code and i'don't know what mail server? is any thing required to get email please tell me

Comment: @neelgurbani I have posted an answer. Your mail() did not work with your code and my mail() does work with the rest of your code. It has to do with the $name parameter you were incorrectly placing in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the incorrect parameters for `mail()`. Try this out:

```
mail($admin_email, $subject, $comment, "From: " . $email);
```

They need to be `$to, $subject, $message` while you had `$to, $name, $subject, $message` (excluding optional parameters).

Comment: but i want to add 5 variables in it. why i can't use this mail($admin_email,$name, $subject, $comment, "From: " . $email);


mail($admin_email, $subject, $comment, "From: " . $email); this function not working still i'm not getting email on this neelaitken@hotmail.com

Comment: You can add the name in the message by adding it there, but not as a separate parameter. `mail($admin_email, $subject, $name . " wrote: " . $comment, "From: " . $email);` would work. Note how it's only one parameter though.

Comment: mail($admin_email, $subject, $name . " wrote the following: " . $comment, "From: " . $email);

this function still not working :( 
try it by yourself and than let me know

Comment: @neelgurbani It does work. :( If it's still not working, you need to check your junk / spam folder in your Email or take a look at the mail settings on the server, but the code I posted will work.

Comment: how can i check mail setting on the server? i'm using xampp

Comment: @neelgurbani Take a look here, there's a lot of things it could be but here's a good start to fixing it: https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=xampp+localhost+mail+server+config Let me know how you make out.